# installing llvm on Pandaboard armv7 using apt-get

Tags: arm, llvm, ubuntu-12.04

Receiving error while adding this repository: `sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main"` I noticed that there was no llvm-arm available there. In general, is there a way to install `llvm > 3-4` on arm-board using `apt-get` ?

Comment: "In general", it's possible to install anything whatsoever using `apt-get` - all it takes is to package up the relevant files, set up a repo to serve them, point `apt` at it, _et voilà!_ Of course, if nobody else has done that already and you just want to install one thing on one machine, then it would be far, far simpler to just manually install the generic binary release. Either way, I think it's much more of a sysadmin question for [su] or [unix.se] rather than a programming one for here - the fact that the package happens to be a compiler isn't at all relevant to the underlying problem.

Comment: true, anyhow built it via `llvm.git` source and took 8 hours :|